# Is this integral indeterminate?

Tags: definite-integrals, indeterminate-forms

What is:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x \, \mathrm{d}x ?$$

Is it $0$ or is it indeterminate ($+\infty - \infty$)?

Comment: An odd function integrated over symmetric limits yields $0$.  One can define your integral as $$\lim_{t \to \infty} \int\limits_{-t}^t x\ dx = \lim\limits_{t \to \infty} 0$$.

Comment: It depends on how you define the improper integration. But most sensible definitions would give zero

Comment: [Read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value), especially where it says this is used to assign values to indeterminate integrals.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The correct statement is that an odd function's integral over symmetric limits, *if it exists*, is equal to zero.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is indeterminate. But it is quite interesting to see why it is indeterminate. If you defined it to be the limit of the integral with extremes $a$ and $-a$ for $ a \to \infty$, then it would be zero. But that is not correct because, long story short, when you take a limit you don’t want the result to depend on how you arrived at that “limit point”. For example, consider it as a function of two variables:

$$ F(a,b)= \int_{a} ^b x dx $$

Then your integral would be the limit of this function as $a \to -\infty$ and $b \to \infty$. Check yourself that this limit doesn’t exist because it depends on how you approach to $\infty$ and $-\infty$.

Of course there are generalisations, or situations where you have to approximate things in a certain way (see the principal value distribution, for instance), but generally speaking that integral is not definite

Comment: One can say more, because even with Riemann analysis an integral $\int_{[a,b]} f(x)dx$ exists (finite) if we have $\int_{[a,b]} |f(x)|dx < \infty$. (the domain of integration does not affect this fact).

Comment: Yeah but it’s not an iff. For instance, take $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. Its integral over $\mathbb{R}$ exists, but the integral of its absolute value is infinite

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that we define 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x dx =\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty}\Big(\int_{-a}^a xdx\Big)
$$
because by symmetry we would like the integral to be $0$. For the same reason, we expect that:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty (x+1) dx =0
$$
since it is also symmetric for $x=-1$. Let us apply the same definition of above:
\begin{multline}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty (x+1) dx =\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty}\Big(\int_{-a}^a (x+1)dx\Big)=\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty}\Big(\int_{-a}^a xdx + \int_{-a}^a dx\Big)
=\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty}\Big(\frac{x^2}{2}\Big|_{-a}^a+x|_{-a}^a\Big)\\=\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty}2a=\infty\,,
\end{multline}

So I think that the correct answer is that it is not convergent, and as spotted before the two distinct extremes are necessary.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral :

> A limitation of the technique of improper integration is that the limit must be taken with respect to one endpoint at a time. Thus, for instance, an improper integral of the form
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$$
>   can be defined by taking two separate limits; to wit
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx = \lim_{a \rightarrow - \infty} \lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-a}^{b}f(x)dx$$provided the double limit is finite. It can also be defined as a pair of distinct improper integrals of the first kind:
>   $$\lim _{a\to -\infty }\int _{a}^{c}f(x)\,dx+\lim _{b\to \infty }\int _{c}^{b}f(x)\,dx$$
>   where c is any convenient point at which to start the integration. This definition also applies when one of these integrals is infinite, or both if they have the same sign.
>   
>   An example of an improper integrals where both endpoints are infinite is the Gaussian integral $ \int _{-\infty }^{\infty }e^{-x^{2}}\,dx={\sqrt {\pi }}$. An example which evaluates to infinity is $ \int _{-\infty }^{\infty }e^{x}\,dx$. But one cannot even define other integrals of this kind unambiguously, such as $ \int _{-\infty }^{\infty }x\,dx$, since the double limit is infinite and the two-integral method $$ \lim _{a\to -\infty }\int _{a}^{c}x\,dx+\lim _{b\to \infty }\int _{c}^{b}x\,dx$$
>   yields $ \infty -\infty$. In this case, one can however define an improper integral in the sense of [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value):
>   $$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }x\,dx=\lim _{b\to \infty }\int _{-b}^{b}x\,dx=0.$$

Note that the Cauchy Principal Value fails to have some basic properties that we would expect of integrals, such as subtitution of variables. If we define $u=x+1$, then $x = u-1$ and $dx = du$, and the limits stay the same (since the value of $u$ when $x$ is $\pm \infty$ is $\pm \infty$), so we have $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(u-1)du$$, and the PV of that will not be zero.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a measure theory (Lebesgue for example) but this is divergent .

So you can use the distributions theory (as the Dirac distribution for example) and for a odd function, the result is $0$

Comment: This isn't really a complete answer; you should write out enough for a reader to follow the results, not just reference the names of concepts. (...especially since, aside from questions of writing, I really don't think the theory of distributions is relevant here)

Comment: Thank you again ! for your relevant remark, indeed it helped me to clarify my answer yesterday about the theory of distributions without the theory of Lebesgue ( a name of concept )as you pointed out .

Answer (score 0):

This integral is improper but does not exist. For an integral of that kind to exist there should be a real $a$ such as both $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{a} x \, \mathrm{d}x$ and $\int\limits_{a}^{+\infty} x \, \mathrm{d}x $ are real numbers. But as we see : $\int\limits_{a}^{+\infty} x \, \mathrm{d}x =\lim_{N\to \infty}{N^2/2-a^2/2}=\infty$ ....

Answer (score 0):

The improper integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\ dx
$$
is not defined, whereas the [principal value integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value)
$$
\textrm{p. v.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x \ dx
$$
exists and equals zero (as is the case for any odd function). Thus, the answer depends on your definitions.

Answer (score 0):

@ Milo Brandt : Thanks for your remark . The distribution is in fact relevant but it's a little difficult to describe in few words .

Answer (score 0):

In mathematics we have to define or postulate existence of objects before use them . 
Often we have to extend the theory . For example the theory of distribution can legitimate and explain your result . It will be too long to develop the theory so i only try to do the taste .
let f(x) = x or f is an arbitrary continuous function from R to R .  f is a continuous function , so the integral of f is define on every [a,b] . For the integral , you can take the Riemann integral for the taste . 
If g is a continuous function ( in fact infinitely derivable but we don't need it for the taste )and if g is 0 outside some [a,b] , we say that g is define with a compact support . Let D the set of all continuous functions  from R to R with arbitrary compact supports . We can show that D is a real vector space . We define a linear form T on the space D , associate to f like this : 
If g € D  we set T(g) = integral of f*g on R .T is call a distribution on R associate to f . We say that the distribution T is odd is T(g) = 0 for all even function g of D . We can show that is f is a continuous  odd function on R , then the distribution T , associate to f , is a odd distribution . 
We now define a sequence . Let n € N * . Let gn a even continuous function on R so that gn(x) = 1  on [ -n ; n ] et gn(x) = 0 outside [ -(n+1), n+1] ( you can draw the graph of gn ) . Let h(x) = 1 on R . We can show that the limit ( in some sense but too long to define )  of the sequence gn is h . f(x) = x is a odd function so the distribution T associate to f is a odd distribution , but the function gn are even functions so T(gn) =0 . We can show that the linear form T is continuous on D in some sense , so that lim T(gn) = T(h) , so T ( h ) = 0 .

Or in the theory of distributions  , the distribution T associate to a continuous function f on R is : T(h) = integral on R of f(x)*h(x) dx , with abusive notation of course  because h is not with compact support !!
So integral on R of x.dx equal 0 
But BE CAREFULL !! it's only a notation , and with bad use , we can do big mistakes, as for example square root of -1 = i , but the square root is not a continuous function on C the set of complex numbers
Sorry for this long answer but without enough rigorous   details of the theory of distributions !